# TCPDF - Problem with Alphanumerical characters (wrong size)

Tags: qr-code, tcpdf

I have a size problem when using TCPDF to generate QR code with only ALPHANUMERICAL characters. My objective: generate the longest URL (with a random part), but keeping the QR code at its lowest size, i.e. 21x21 modules (version1).
Documentation ([QRcode.com](http://www.qrcode.com/en/about/version.html)) reports that using only alphanumerical characters set ([thonky.com](https://www.thonky.com/qr-code-tutorial/alphanumeric-table)), URL can be 25 characters long with ERC set to L.

Using write2DBarCode with this 25 Alphanumerical URL leads to version1 (21x21mod) QR as expected

```
$pdf->write2DBarcode('HTTP://SITE-COM/123456789', 'QRCODE,L', 20, 20, 40, 40, $style, 'N');
```

but changing to this other URL, with also 25 Alphanumerical, I get a version 2 (25x25mod) QR code, whereas a version 1 could be done ([Tested on Nayuki](https://www.nayuki.io/page/qr-code-generator-library))

```
$pdf->write2DBarcode('HTTP://TXT-CH/AYAWEQYAF4A', 'QRCODE,L', 20, 70, 40, 40, $style, 'N');
```

I join the TCPDF Outputs of the 2 QR codes given as examples [TCPDF Outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COKUq.png)

Thank you in advance for your help on this wonderful TCPDF library.

Comment: Please show the output of both QR Codes from TCPDF. Maybe it contains extra metadata like an ECI segment.

Comment: @Nayuki Thank you for your answer. Please find here above the outputs of both QR Code, in the initial post that I completed. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: The TCPDF software that you are using is suboptimal. It is generating a full 4-bit terminator even when a shorter one suffices. Please contact the software's authors to fix the problem. You can link them to this thread.

---

So I cropped your image into two QR Code images, and submitted them to [ZXing Decoder Online](https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx) and [KaarPoSoft QR Decode with debug output](http://qrlogo.kaarposoft.dk/qrdecode.html).

ZXing, first barcode:

```
Decode Succeeded
Raw text              HTTP://SITE-COM/123456789
Raw bytes             20 83 1a a6 5f 9f d5 b4 75 3e 8d 20 48 81 23 db 91 8a 80
Barcode format        QR_CODE
Parsed Result Type    URI
Parsed Result         HTTP://SITE-COM/123456789
```

ZXing, second barcode:

```
Decode Succeeded
Raw text              HTTP://TXT-CH/AYAWEQYAF4A
Raw bytes             20 cb 1a a6 5f 9f d6 5e ae 82 ca 0f 21 e2 52 18 11 53 94 00 ec 11 ec 11 ec 11 ec 11 ec 11 ec 11 ec 11
Barcode format        QR_CODE
Parsed Result Type    URI
Parsed Result HTTP://TXT-CH/AYAWEQYAF4A
```

KaarPoSoft, first barcode:

```
Debug output
skew_limit=7.21875
skew=0
left=31 right=427 top=27 bottom=423
size=397
matchVersion version=1 finder0=64 finder1=64 finder2=64
matchVersion version=1 timing0=1 timing1=1 alignment=1
matchVersion version=1 format_NW =14 0 format_NESW =14 1 format = 14 ecl = 1 mask = 6
matchVersion version=1 grades(F(V)TAF): 4444->4
findModuleSize matchVersion version=1 grade=4
findModuleSize version=1 grade=4 error_correction_level=1 mask=6
getCodewords mask=6 length=26
getCodewords = 32,131,26,166,95,159,213,180,117,62,141,32,72,129,35,219,145,138,128,62,191,105,157,147,176,164
setBlocks n_blocks_first=1 n_blocks_second=0 n_blocks=1 n_block_words_first=19 n_block_words_second=0 n_block_ec_words=7 total=26
setBlocks block 0 (26): 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25
RS calculateSyndroms: No errors
correctErrors in = 32,131,26,166,95,159,213,180,117,62,141,32,72,129,35,219,145,138,128,62,191,105,157,147,176,164
correctErrors out = 32,131,26,166,95,159,213,180,117,62,141,32,72,129,35,219,145,138,128
error_grade=4
extractData bytes in (19) = 32,131,26,166,95,159,213,180,117,62,141,32,72,129,35,219,145,138,128
extractData mode = 2
extractAlphanum charcount = 16
extractData mode = 1
extractNumeric charcount = 9
extractData mode = 0
extractData data(25) = 72,84,84,80,58,47,47,83,73,84,69,45,67,79,77,47,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57
```

KaarPoSoft, second barcode:

```
Debug output
skew_limit=7.015625
skew=1
left=21 right=417 top=30 bottom=425
size=396.5
findModuleSize matchVersion version=1 grade=0
matchVersion version=2 finder0=64 finder1=64 finder2=64
matchVersion version=2 timing0=1 timing1=1 alignment=1
matchVersion version=2 format_NW =14 0 format_NESW =14 1 format = 14 ecl = 1 mask = 6
matchVersion version=2 grades(F(V)TAF): 4444->4
findModuleSize matchVersion version=2 grade=4
findModuleSize version=2 grade=4 error_correction_level=1 mask=6
getCodewords mask=6 length=44
getCodewords = 32,203,26,166,95,159,214,94,174,130,202,15,33,226,82,24,17,83,148,0,236,17,236,17,236,17,236,17,236,17,236,17,236,17,87,194,99,197,7,184,131,204,163,52
setBlocks n_blocks_first=1 n_blocks_second=0 n_blocks=1 n_block_words_first=34 n_block_words_second=0 n_block_ec_words=10 total=44
setBlocks block 0 (44): 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43
RS calculateSyndroms: No errors
correctErrors in = 32,203,26,166,95,159,214,94,174,130,202,15,33,226,82,24,17,83,148,0,236,17,236,17,236,17,236,17,236,17,236,17,236,17,87,194,99,197,7,184,131,204,163,52
correctErrors out = 32,203,26,166,95,159,214,94,174,130,202,15,33,226,82,24,17,83,148,0,236,17,236,17,236,17,236,17,236,17,236,17,236,17
error_grade=4
extractData bytes in (34) = 32,203,26,166,95,159,214,94,174,130,202,15,33,226,82,24,17,83,148,0,236,17,236,17,236,17,236,17,236,17,236,17,236,17
extractData mode = 2
extractAlphanum charcount = 25
extractData mode = 0
extractData data(25) = 72,84,84,80,58,47,47,84,88,84,45,67,72,47,65,89,65,87,69,81,89,65,70,52,65
```

Both QR Codes appear to have no problems regarding error correction or format violations.

---

From the KaarPoSoft output, we can see the segments in the QR Codes.

The first barcode has two segments:

1. Alphanumeric mode, count = 16, text = "HTTP://SITE-COM/". Segment bit length = 4 (mode) + 9 (count) + 88 (data) = 101 bits.
2. Numeric mode, count = 9, text = "123456789". Segment bit length = 4 (mode) + 10 (count) + 30 (data) = 44 bits.

The second barcode has one segment:

1. Alphanumeric mode, count = 25, text = "HTTP://TXT-CH/AYAWEQYAF4A". Segment bit length = 4 (mode) + 9 (count) + 138 (data) = 151 bits.

Now, a QR Code at version 1 with low error correction level has capacity for 19 data codeword bytes, or 152 bits. The first barcode uses 101 + 44 = 145 bits = 19 bytes (rounded up), so it fits. The second barcode uses 151 bits = 19 bytes (rounded up), so it fits. So in theory, both lists of segments of text data should fit in version 1 low ECC.

According to the QR spec, after the list of segments ends, these bits are appended:

1. (TERM) Up to four "0" bits (but less if the data capacity is reached) for the terminator pseudo-mode.
2. (BITPAD) Zero to seven "0" bits to fill up the last partial byte.
3. (BYTEPAD) Alternating bytes of 0xEC and 0x11 until the data capacity is reached.

---

Let's dissect what actually happened. Convert the ZXing hexadecimal byte output to binary, and annotate the fields.

First barcode:

```
20 83 1a a6 5f 9f d5 b4 75 3e 8d 20 48 81 23 db 91 8a 80
0010  000010000 [88 bits]  0001  0000001001 [30 bits] 0000  000  (Total length = 152 bits)
^Mode ^Count    ^Data      ^Mode ^Count     ^Data     ^TERM ^BITPAD
```

Second barcode:

```
20 cb 1a a6 5f 9f d6 5e ae 82 ca 0f 21 e2 52 18 11 53 94 00 ec 11 ec 11 ec 11 ec 11 ec 11 ec 11 ec 11
0010  000011001 [138 bits] | 0000  00000   11101100 00010001 [...]  (Total length = 272 bits)
^Mode ^Count    ^Data      | ^TERM ^BITPAD ^BYTEPAD
```

Note that in the second barcode, at the position `|` just before the TERMinator, there are 151 bits on the left side. The terminator is normally four "0" bits, but is allowed to be shortened if the capacity (of 152 bits) is reached. So the optimal terminator is a single bit of "0", and then there must be no bit padding and no byte padding.

Comment: Thank you very much @Nayuki for this wonderfully detailed answer.

Comment: @Nicola Asuni , is there a possibility to update the TCPDF library on this point ?

Comment: If you feel that my answer is satisfactory, please click on the checkbox to mark it as accepted.